# Injecting CSS rules into the page in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, code-injection, custom-font

I'm writing a JavaScript to inject a new CSS rule into pages in Android browser in order to display some text in a custom CSS font (after some replacement).

Here is how I tried to inject the CSS rule:

```
var css = '@font-face {font-family:"font"; src:url(http://www.example.com/font.ttf);} si{font-family:"font"}';
if(document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0]){
   var style = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0];
} else {
   var style = document.createElement("style");
   style.type = "text/css";
   document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(style);
}
var sheet = style.sheet;
sheet.insertRule(css, sheet.cssRules.length);
```

Then the text is replaced using a JavaScript XPath implementation. Replacing lines are in this model:

```
text = text.replace(/\'/g, "<si>♥</si>");
```

The text replacement happens perfectly. But the injecting CSS rule part is not working. The replaced text is just shown as `<si>♥</si>` (with tags also printed).  :(

Can anyone please correct my code of injecting CSS rule or please suggest some other way to do this.

Thanks!

**Update: I'm emulating this in Android 2.2 which supports CSS fonts.**

Answer (score 1):

@font-face seems to be broken on Android 2.0 and 2.1 ([bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4448)).

Comment: Yes, Android 2.0 & 2.1 do not support CSS fonts. But I'm emulating this in Android 2.2 which supports CSS fonts. Therefore I should be able to do this somehow.

Comment: I don't have the 2.2 SDK installed, but if I test your example in Chromium, it doesn't work either. It does however, if I split the css in two variables, one for each rule (var css1 = '@font-face{...}'; var css2 = 'si{...}';). Seems like you can insert only one rule at a time using insertRule.