# How can I apply a css style to the "remote html" inside WebView after html is loaded

Tags: android, android-webview

Let's say I want to open Google's homepage inside a WebView with a custom css.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

How can I change the background color to black after page is fully loaded?

Comment: Use Javascript injection.

Comment: @R. L  I tried to use js injection with no luck. Can you please provide me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Javascript injection, you can load a page and change the class styles by reloading it with a custom Javascript. For example:

```
view.loadUrl("your.website.com");
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0].style.backgroundColor='black';");
```

Comment: Is it possible to set font-family from a ttf file using the same way?

Comment: you might want to refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949056/injecting-css-rules-into-the-page-in-android-browser

Comment: Can you please take a look to this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015672/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-css-style-inside-webview-after-html-is-loaded