# How can I change the "font-family" css style inside WebView after html is loaded

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to change "font-family" with javascript injection. Here is my code.

```
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
    "css = '@font-face {font-family: \"myface\";src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/DroidSansArmenian.ttf\");}';"+
    "css = css + '.opennewstitle { font-family: \"myface\";}';"+
    "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];"+
    "var s = document.createElement('style');"+
    "s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');"+
    "s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));"+
    "head.appendChild(s);"+
 "})()");
            }
        });

        String url = "http://m.news.am/arm/news/195853.html";
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

It doesn't work, but the js code works inside Chrome browser.

Comment: Use `loadDataWithBaseURL`. Refer this [load-a-html-file-at-runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416182/how-to-create-update-load-a-html-file-at-runtime/18417164#18417164)

Comment: How can I get htmlString from the url?

Comment: just use your string that you use inside `myWebView.loadUrl(..)` as htmlString.

Comment: it's not a "html data string", it is just a url..

Comment: ohhhh.... i made a mistake i assume that you load runtime htmlscript.

Comment: Also you cant change type face for webview when you call url in webview.